# How to make wpf datagrid certain rows readonly for a particular date value in the row

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

Some of the rows in my WPF datagrid has to be made readonly while loading the datagrid depending on a date field column in the datagrid row. How can this be achived. Can anybody help me with some sample code for this. Say if Date Field value is greater than a particular date make the row in the datagrid readonly. I need it on when datagrid is loaded.

Comment: pleasae mark it as answer if it really helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you can use ValueConverter for this and in AutogeneratingColumn event  you can disable cell on the basis of value. Here i assumed that date that you want to compare is fixed and common for all the rows and they are known before binding of the data to the datagrid.

Solutions:

Create a Value Converter which will return true or false(or whichever values u might want)
and in autogenerating column set  that particular column readonly. As autogenerating column event will fire for all the columns . Hence it will automatically set readonly to all the columns and hence can achieve the functionality.

or

handle Loaded event of the datagrid  and after that in loaded event you can get all the values of columns and rows and by iterating all the rows you can make them readonly
on the basis of your requirement.

As right now, I dont have visual studio  installed with me so not able to show you exact code.

if u still have any doubt.please let me know and before applying solution please also consider my assumptions as well.